# Forward to different users depending on labels - Gmail Apps Script

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to create an Apps Script for Gmail, so that all messages labelled `product-related` and `product-a` are forwarded to the producta@gmail.com address, and all messages labelled "product-related" and `product-b` are forwarded to the productb@gmail.com address.

The script will be launched via a card, so there is no need for more automation.

Here's the code I did:

```js
function testforward1() {
  var label = "product-related";
  //var interval = 2000;          
  //var date = new Date();
  //var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:' + label);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    if (label == "product-a" && "product-related") {
      var recipient = 'producta@gmail.com';
      var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
      //var attachment = messages[i].getAttachments();
      for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
        var body = messages[j].getBody();
        messages[j].forward(recipient, {
          htmlBody: body
        });
      }
    }
    if (label == "product-b" && "product-related") {
      var recipient1 = 'productb@gmail.com';
      var messages1 = threads[i].getMessages();
      //var attachment1 = messages1[i].getAttachments();
      for (var j = 0; j < messages1.length; j++) {
        var body1 = messages1[j].getBody();
        messages1[j].forward(recipient1, {
          htmlBody: body1
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I guess I did something wrong with the variables, but I'm a total beginner with Google Apps Scripts, and I already spent more than 10 hours on this, with no success.

I got no email transferred with this, but the execution gives no error. And I was wondering if the `var label  = "product-related";` should be replaced with something else?

I will be grateful if you could give me some help on this!

Comment: Hi there! After testing this I have some questions. I assume that you want to look for all the threads with a `product-related` tag. Then I guess that you want to check which one of those has also a `product-a` tag. If my understanding is correct, then you need to update `if (label == "product-a" && "product-related") {` with [`GmailLabel.getName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label#getname). The goal should be to read all the tags of the `product-related` threads, and then check if they match `product-a`. Please test this approach and share your findings.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer.
Actually, emails with both "product-related" and "product-a" labels should be forwarded to producta@gmail.com, and emails with both "product-related" and "product-b" should be forwarded to productb@gmail.com.
The thing is that I don't know if and how to get rid of the var label, because it is used in var threads = GmailApp.search('label:' + label);

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron any further help on this? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Thank you for your support. I have been studying the code, but I don't see where you need help. Could you please share some examples? Also, please confirm what does «*how to get rid of the var label*» means. Why can't you delete that line?

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron The code does not work: no email is transferred.
I don't know how to remove the label because it is used in `var threads = GmailApp.search('label:' + label);`.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work (I think)! :)

```
function testforward1() {
 var threadsa = GmailApp.search('label: product-related label: product-a');
 for (var i = 0; i < threadsa.length; i++) {
  var recipient = 'producta@gmail.com';
  var messages = threadsa[i].getMessages();
  for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
   var body = messages[j].getBody();
   messages[j].forward(recipient,{htmlBody: body});
  }
 }
var threadsb = GmailApp.search('label: product-related label: product-b');
for (var i = 0; i < threadsb.length; i++) {
 var recipient = 'productb@gmail.com';
 var messages = threadsb[i].getMessages();
 for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
  var body = messages[j].getBody();
  messages[j].forward(recipient,{htmlBody: body});
 }
 }
}
```

Now I still have a few more functions to implement, but the basic forwarding function works, and it's the most important.

Comment: Purely out of curiousity, wouldn't you have to apply some kind of `forwardedProdA` and `forwardedProdB` labels and remove these labels and apply those to avert any looping? I mean, you've obviously not had to do that, I'm just trying to understand how it doesn't loop, is all.